# send custom xmpp IQ in ios

Tags: ios, xmppframework

I want to send the following IQ to open fire server:

```
<iq type="get">
<regdata xmlns="abc">
<username>cooper</username>
<emailid>cooper@hotmail.com</emailid>
<password>cooperpass</password>
<dob>11-12-1979</dob>
<gender>male</gender>
</regdata>
</iq>
```

What shall be the command in Xcode?

I'm using the below mentioned script but its not working.

```
NSXMLElement *regdata = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"regdata" xmlns:@"abc"];
NSXMLElement *iq = [NSXMLElement elementWithName:@"iq"];
XMPPJID *myJID = self.xmppStream.myJID;

[iq addAttributeWithName:@"type" stringValue:@"get"];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"from" stringValue:myJID.description];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"to" stringValue:myJID.domain];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"username" stringValue:txtName.text];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"emailid" stringValue:txtEmail.text];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"password" stringValue:txtPassword.text];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"dob" stringValue:txtDOB.text];
[iq addAttributeWithName:@"gender" stringValue:txtGender.text];


[iq addChild:regdata];
[self.xmppStream sendElement:iq];
```